# Removal of the "words" tag

Tags: feature-request, tagging

[words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) is used in many questions, but it doesn't seem to have a specific meaning. All the questions are about words, even the one asking about a phrase or a sentence.

We should remove the tag.

Comment: In hearty agreement here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I kind of agree, and there is a similar problem in that I don't know what the distinction between [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) and [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) is. If anything, they should be made synonyms. I would vote for making [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) a synonym of [vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) because the latter I think has a sense of being about the words themselves rather than the words simply being there as part of a question about something else.

Comment: I agree. _Words_ could be a synonym of _vocabulary_.

Comment: I hadn't realised multiple tags can be classed as synonyms, but that being so I would keep *Words* as a synonym for *vocabulary* rather than delete it entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't all possible uses of 'words' already more usefully sub-categorized?  Etymology, grammaticality, word-choice, meaning/semantics, slang, spelling, nouns, verbs, et al.  I'm not sure the 'words' tag adds anything.  It's a meta tag that really doesn't seem to do much work.